# Trying to log an array in a loop, and return a string if array index is equal to a certain variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have a simple array that I want to run in a loop. While I want to log each value of the array to the console, I also want to log a string **only IF** the index of the array matches the value of a variable..

Here is what I got.

```
let myVal = 10;
let digit = [12,4,11,10]

for (let i = 0; i < digit.length; i++) {
  console.log(digit[i]);
  if (myVal == digit[3]) {
    console.log(digit[3] && ' Hooray!');
  }
}
```

What I am seeing is the console is logging both, so I get this:

> 12 
>   Check!
>   4
>   Check!
>   11
>   Check!
>   10
>   Check!

I am looking for something like this:

> 12
>   4
>   11
>   10 Check!

Comment: `if (myVal == digit[3])` to `if (myVal == digit[i])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're in a loop, you won't need to check for digit[3], you can just check for digit[i].

```js
let myVal = 10;
let digit = [12, 4, 11, 10];

for (let i = 0; i < digit.length; i++) {
    if (digit[i] == myVal){
        console.log(digit[i] + ' Hooray!');
    } else {
      console.log(digit[i]);
    }
}
```

I also added an else for printing the rest of the digits separately. Lastly, you'll want to use "+" instead of "&&" if you want to append text to your result.

Comment: funny how i flip the if and you did too. wooow wait you also added my else. You can remove the ``{}`` when you only run 1 line of code inside

Comment: @Just_some_Noob what aspect of my answer made you change the result?

Comment: @GerardoBLANCO yeah, it made more sense for me to flip the equality check. Great minds think alike! I always add the extra curly braces and semicolons too... just helps me see the structure of the code better :)

Answer (score 3):

You want check the indexes ?

```
for (let i = 0; i < digit.length; i++) {
    console.log(digit[i]);
    if (myVal == digit[i]) //check the index not digit[3] every loop
        console.log(digit[i] + ' Hooray!');   //print the index using string concatenation
}
```

im also noob :)

Answer (score 0):

Small error on your loop.

Always use your iterator when you have an if inside a loop

Hope it helps

```js
let myVal = 10;
let digit = [12, 4, 11, 10]

for (let i = 0; i < digit.length; i++) {
  if (digit[i] == myVal)
    console.log(digit[3] + ' Check!');
  else
    console.log(digit[i]);
}
```

Comment: @Just_some_Noob happy to help

Comment: @Just_some_Noob what aspect of my answer made you change the result?4

Comment: thisisdamon let me know that I didn't need to check for digit[3] since it was a loop. Also he just agave a little more explanation to his response. I appreciate your help as well!

Answer (score 0):

You need to evaluate against the current index.

I would suggest something like this

```
let myVal = 10;
let digit = [12, 4, 11, 10]
for (let i = 0; i < digit.length; i++){
    if (digit[i] == myVal)
        console.log(digit[i] + 'Hooray!');
    } else {
        console.log(digit[i]);
    }
}
```

Or just use a for in loop which looks like this:

```
for (x in digit) {
    if (digit[x] == myVal)
        console.log(digit[x] + 'Hooray!');
    } else {
        console.log(digit[x]);
    }
}
```

Also && is used for "and" in evaluations and + is used for concatenation of string.